# How to make entry in systems registry in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, registry

I have a desktop application and developing an installer script. I need to check for previous installations whenever this script run. I have no idea how to access registry in flex. any help or reference will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex, or more specifically AIR/AS3, does not provide access to the Windows Registry.  You'll have to build you're own Native Extension to expose this functionality.

---

Since I was asked for some resource links...

Here are some blogs posts on creating a [Native Extension in Windows](http://quetwo.com/2011/10/31/creating-an-windows-air-native-extension-with-eclipse-part-1/).
Here are some generic information on [building Native Extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html).

And finally, Google should tell you how to [access the Windows Registry from C](https://www.google.com/search?q=Access%20Windows%20Registry%20from%20C&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a); which is what you want to do inside your Native Extension.

Comment: thanks for reply can you refer any documents or examples i should go through ?

Comment: I added some resource links; but remember that Google is your friend.  If you're looking for a consultant to help with this project; feel free to contact me privately.  I'd have a lot of fun with a project like this.

Comment: sure, but first let me try my self :) thanks for every thing :).